# Cryptic error on templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am rather stumped by the error message I am seeing for a piece of code I am working on currently. I've tried to extract the most relevant pieces of the code to make it easy on the eyes.

The error I see:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘`Map(Print&, std::shared_ptr< LinkedList< int> >&)`’
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   cannot convert ‘`p`’ (type ‘`Print`’) to type ‘`int`’

Why is the compiler trying to cast `Print` to `int` at all?

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
  using NodeType = std::shared_ptr<LinkedList>;
  ... Other things
}

template<class Func, typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::NodeType Map(Func func, typename  LinkedList<T>::NodeType seq)
{
  // Some stuff
}

class Print
{
 public:

 int operator()(int i)
 {
     cout << i << endl;
     return i;
 }
};

void main()
{
  Print p;
  auto one = std::make_shared< LinkedList <int>> ();
  auto result = Map<int>(p, one);  << ---- Error
}
```

gcc 4.8.4

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You told the compiler `Func=int` here `Map<int>(p, one)`. You need `Map<Print, int>(p, one)`

Comment: `auto result = Map<int>(p, one);` isn't this you try to refer p whic is `Print` into `int` ?

Comment: If you swap the template parameters, you can specify `Map<int>(p, one)` and let `Func` be deduced as `Print`.

Comment: Aah yes of course. Map<Print, int> *facepalm*. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @melak47 I guess that works too but I wanted to know why this format was causing the error.

Comment: IMHO, the error comes from limits of the type deduction algorithm of C++. In your example, the type needed to be deduced is a member type LLp::NodeType, where LLp is also parameterized; but this form is not listed in [Deduction from a type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). If you "simplify" this form by, for example, letting LLp is a concrete type; or putting Map into the scope (as in the answer of @Christopher), then there would be no error.

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this, I would define Map as an inline friend of LinkedList.  This removes problems with dependent type deduction, so you can call `Map` without any explicit template parameters.

Keep in mind that the only way for the compiler to find a function defined like this is with Argument-Dependent Lookup -- so it only works when a `LinkedList` object is passed as one of the function's arguments.  Also inline friends seem to freak people out.

But it goes a long way to clean up and simplify the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    using NodeType = std::shared_ptr<LinkedList>;


    template <typename Func>
    friend NodeType Map(Func func, NodeType seq) {
        return seq;
    }

};

class Print
{
public:
    int operator()(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        return i;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Print p;
  auto one = std::make_shared< LinkedList<int> >();
  auto result = Map(p, one);
}
```

Comment: Indeed this was the first implementation I had. I am trying to emulate the Map function in Clojure/Lisp. Making Map a member of the LinkedList would imply it can access private members and Map is not a property of a LinkedList. It should be an operation on the LinkedList. Later on I would like to expand this to a more generic form. Map over any sequence.

Comment: Well Map isn't a member here, it's just a friend.  It will be used as a "free" function `Map(p,one)` while a member would be used like `p->Map(one)`.  But it does have access to private members and if its final implementation is large, it could really uglify the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a new answer after gaining a better understanding of OP's goal.  My first answer addressed difficulties related to dependent template type parameters encountered when compiling some example code, so I think it is still a valid answer.

This answer demonstrates creating a custom container class and how to write a generic `Map` function which iterates over containers, calling a custom function object for each element, and adding each result to another container which is finally returned by the function.

The container in this example is a linked list, defined with a minimal set of features, only enough for this example to compile and run.

The linked list class supplies `begin()` and `end()` functions which return iterator objects which are used for traversing the list. Only non-constant versions are defined here, versions for returning constant iterators should also be added for when the LinkedList object is const.

The `Map` function here takes a functor and a container object as arguments.  All argument types are deduced, so there is no need to explicitly supply template parameters.  The container is passed by value to avoid problems with const-correctness in LinkedList, and also because `LinkedList`'s (default) copy constructor doesn't do a lot of work -- it only needs to copy two `shared_ptr` objects, rather than perform a deep copy of all contained data.

This `Map` is very simple, additional, improved versions might take two iterators (a begin and end), take a const reference to the container object (to avoid useless copying), or use type traits to handle containers which need to be accessed in special ways.

As it is here, `Map` should work with other containers, like std::vector, because it uses the standard iterator API.

The original version of LinkedList was just maintained as a pointer to a single list node.  In the code below, `LinkedList` is real a container object which keeps (smart) pointers to the first and last `Node` objects.  We need to access pointers to both the `head` and `tail` nodes here, so keeping a pointer to just one node would be inadequate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    struct Node;
    using NodeType = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
    struct Node {
        NodeType   next;
        T          value;
    };

    class forward_iterator {
        NodeType cur_node;
    public:
        forward_iterator() {}
        forward_iterator(NodeType cur_node) : cur_node(cur_node) {}
        T& operator * () { return cur_node->value; }
        forward_iterator& operator ++ () { cur_node = cur_node->next; return *this; }
        bool operator == (const forward_iterator& it) const { return cur_node == it.cur_node; }
        bool operator != (const forward_iterator& it) const { return !operator == (it); }
    };

    void push_back(const T& t) {
        NodeType node = std::make_shared<Node>();
        if(tail) {
            tail->next = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {
            head = tail = node;
        }
        node->value = t;
    }

    forward_iterator begin() { return forward_iterator(head); }
    forward_iterator end()   { return forward_iterator(); }

protected:
    NodeType head, tail;
};

inline std::string upper_case(const std::string& s) {
    std::string r;
    for(auto c : s) {
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') c = c - 'a' + 'A';
        r.push_back(c);
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename Func, typename S>
inline S Map(Func func, S seq) {
    S result;
    for(const auto& elem : seq) {
        result.push_back(func(elem));
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    // add strings to a LinkedList of strings named "original"
    static const char* my_data[] = { "Hello", "1234", "John Cena", "xd" };
    LinkedList<std::string> original;
    for(auto cstr : my_data) { original.push_back(cstr); }

    // dump "original" to cout
    std::cout << "-- original --\n";
    for(const auto& s : original) { std::cout << s << '\n'; }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Run the generic Map function with "original" as input
    // A lambda will be called for each element and
    // its returned value added to the result, named "mapped".
    // A functor object may be used in place of the lambda
    auto mapped = Map(
        [](const std::string& s) { return upper_case(s); },
        original);

    // dump "mapped" to cout
    std::cout << "-- mapped --\n";
    for(const auto& s : mapped) { std::cout << s << '\n'; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```